# Install Flycheck on emacs

Tags: emacs

this is my first post here I need your help to use flycheck
I use last version of fedora

I didnt find this file 
`$HOME/.emacs.d/init.el`.
so I modified this
`/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/desktop-entry-mode-init.el`

then I enter to Emacs and press

```
ESC
:
M-x (alt-x as I believe)
```

(the problem comes heres)
doesnt show `package-install` or `list-packages` commands
as is shown here

`http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/installation.html`

I dont know if its right or not what Im doing. Im almost 2 hours trying to install this checker, hope you help me

Comment: if you are just starting with emacs you may want to look at a "pre-packaged" configuration like Emacs Prelude which includes many helpful things already set up. Installing and configuring flycheck is probably not a good "day one" activity for a new emacs user.

Comment: You shouldn't have modified that file, you should have created a new, empty file in the expected location. and added your setup to that. `list-packages` works fine on Ubuntu without emacs customisations; it should work fine in Fedora, as well. Undo your changes, then try again with a "clean" emacs.

Comment: Why did you do `Esc-:`? Just `M-x`, then type `list-packages`.

Comment: It worked. I shouldnt have used Esc-: